# Matplotlib bar plot with pandas Timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am having trouble making this very simple example work:

```
from numpy import datetime64
from pandas import Series
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

x = Series ([datetime64("2016-01-01"),datetime64("2016-02-01")]).astype(datetime)
y = Series ([0.1 , 0.2])

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, y, width=10)
ax.xaxis_date()

plt.show()
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'
```

Note the `astype(datetime)` piece - that is something I tried after [reading this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376080/plot-numpy-datetime64-with-matplotlib). Without that piece, I get the same error.

On the other hand, the example works well enough with plain `datetime64` types - that is, changing these two lines:

```
x = [datetime64("2016-01-01"),datetime64("2016-02-01")]
y = [0.1 , 0.2]
```

So the issue must be the `Timestamp` type that pandas converts the `datetime64` objects into.  Is there a way to make this work with `Timestamp` directly, and not revert to `datetime64`?  I'm using `Series`/`Timestamp` here because my real objective is plotting series from a `DataFrame`.  (Note: I cannot use the `DataFrame` plotting methods because my real example is inside a seaborn `FacetGrid` and I have to use matplotlib directly.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
ax.bar(x.values, y, width=10)
```

when using the Series objects. The issue is that you are not sending an object that is similar to an array, it is an indexed array that matplotlib does not know how to handle. `values` returns only the array

Answer (score 1):

As your objective is plotting series from a DataFrame, maybe you can just use `pd.DataFrame.plot`?

```
from numpy import datetime64
from pandas import Series
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
%matplotlib inline

x = Series ([datetime64("2016-01-01"),datetime64("2016-02-01")])
y = Series ([0.1 , 0.2])

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
df.plot.bar(x='x', y='y')
```

[image: image produced]

Comment: I wish!  Unfortunately in my real problem I am working inside a seaborn `FacetGrid` and need to use `matplotlib` directly.